# Como Trabalhar com Eventos no Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Olá estou atualmente trabalhando com um projeto de verificação de acesso. Eu preciso que quando a pessoa tenha acesso concedida pelo sistema acione um som "passagem autorizada com sucesso", a minha pergunta é eu consigo fazer isso com Eventos do laravel?

Comment: Não faz. Os eventos do Laravel são para tratar situações de *backend* e tratá-las de forma assíncrona por meio das filas de execução. Emitir um som parece ser responsabilidade do *frontend* e, provavelmente, coisa para ser feito com JavaScript.

Comment: Obrigada pela resposta! Você me indicaria uma forma de fazer via JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegue, mas também tem outra formas de fazer. Você pode gravar Flash Data, que te ma vida de 1 ciclo apenas (uma vez atualizada a página ele deixa de existir) e você executa um scritp quando o flash existir, ou seja quando logar pela primeira vez você definine o flash, confere se existe, execute o javascript (audio) e quando o usuário trocar de págiana deixa de existir aquele flash e também o audio só tocara novamente eno proximo login.

Controller :

```
Session::flash('message', 'This is a message!');
```

View

```
@if(Session::has('message'))
<script ......> </script>
endif
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/session#storing-data